# Nodewebkit Self Updating - Can I overwrite the program file I am using?

Tags: overwrite, node-webkit, self-updating

before you say - just try it, I don't want to do anything funny that will cause problems. So I am asking the people who know these things already.

Say I have my Nodewebkit program app.exe. In it there is an update button which will download the newest version of the program. Then it will want to overwrite the app.exe (the program that is running).

Is this last thing allowable in windows (and also Mac and Linux)?

Comment: You can't overwrite an active EXE in Windows, so you will need a launcher app that checks for an update, download it and then launch it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am a hobby programmer, and am not sure how this could be done. I have been searching for an example online, but as yet cannot find one. Do you know of an example online?

Comment: Unfortunately, for Node Webkit, I haven't found a cross-platform solution yet. We've rolled our own - but it's not perfect.